# Create a \savebox in a Group and have it available outside of group

Tags: boxes, grouping

The MWE below creates a `\savebox` within a group which results in several blank lines:

[image]

If I comment out the`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` I get the desired results:

[image]

My thinking was that adding the `\global` should have fixed this issue.

So, how do I create and define `\savebox` within a group and yet be able to use the outside of the group?

### Notes:

- While the MWE here does not need grouping my actual use case does, so I would really prefer to not have to eliminate the grouping.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\MyLink}[2]{%
\begingroup
    \ifcsdef{MyBox #1-#2}{%
    }{%
        \typeout{*** Defined savebox for #1-#2}%
        \global\expandafter\newsavebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname%
        \global\expandafter\savebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname{#2: #1}%
    }%
    \expandafter\usebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname%
\endgroup
}%


\begin{document}
    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 
    
    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 
    
    \MyLink{http://www.apple.org}{A} 
    
    \MyLink{http://www.google.com}{G} 

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: why a box here (allocating a box every use is not usually recommended, even though etex means you have rather more than in classic tex)

Comment: `\global\savebox` is definitely not going to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: My actual use case is more involved, so the reason is for efficiency to save doing things thousands of times.

Comment: @PeterGrill are you sure it's that much more efficient than a macro?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Just did a small test. Using the solution you posted required less than 1/3 the elapsed time.

Comment: @PeterGrill but perhaps you can optimise the macros (edef instead of def (essentially)) also is that saving 1/3 second or 1/3 of an hour? But anyway if you accept mine and not egreg's you are forgiven any such sins.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Test Results: no caching: 182466, using `\xdef` 177718, using your `\setbox` solution 54390. Not sure what the time units are.

Comment: With this, you can't use links in footnotes, or rather they will not obey any font changing context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that using a locally allocated box here is the wrong thing to do but to do it, just use the primitive commands to set the content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\MyLink}[2]{%
\begingroup
    \ifcsdef{MyBox #1-#2}{%
    }{%
        \typeout{*** Defined savebox for #1-#2}%
        \global\expandafter\newsavebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname%
        \global\expandafter\setbox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname\hbox{{#2: #1}}%
    }%
    \expandafter\usebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname%
\endgroup
}%


\begin{document}
    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 

    \MyLink{http://www.apple.org}{A} 

    \MyLink{http://www.google.com}{G} 

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's see what `\global\savebox\foo` does:

1. `\global` expands `\savebox` so the input stream is

   ```
   \global\@ifnextchar ({\@savepicbox \foo}{\@ifnextchar [{\@savebox #1}{\sbox \foo}}
   ```
2. `\global` expands `\@ifnextchar`, so the input stream is

   ```
   \global\let\reserved@d=( [...]
   ```

   (where `[...]` denote irrelevant tokens).
3. `\global` is applied to `\let`.

Note that `\global` doesn't disappear until it finds a token it can apply to (`\def`, `\let`, a register address and so on; in general, an assignment).

This explains why you don't get errors, but also why you don't get a global setting for your box.

Doing `\global\sbox\foo{tokens}` would work, because the first expansion step triggered by `\global` is

```
\global\setbox\foo\hbox{\color@setgroup tokens\color@endgroup}
```

However, you may be using a stripped down example and perhaps you need the full force of `\savebox`, instead of `\sbox`, so you can use a temporary box register for the construction and then globally set the new register to be the same as the built box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newsavebox{\mylinkbox}
\newcommand*{\MyLink}[2]{%
\begingroup
    \ifcsdef{MyBox #1-#2}{%
    }{%
        \typeout{*** Defined savebox for #1-#2}%
        \global\expandafter\newsavebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname
        \savebox\mylinkbox{#2: #1}%
        \global\expandafter\setbox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname\box\mylinkbox
    }%
    \expandafter\usebox\csname MyBox #1-#2\endcsname
\endgroup
}


\begin{document}
    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W}

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W}

    \MyLink{http://www.apple.org}{A}

    \MyLink{http://www.google.com}{G}

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W}

    \MyLink{http://www.wikipedia.org}{W}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, example is heavily stripped down, but I am not sure I know what the "full force of \savebox" is. Is there a question here that explains what `\savebox` will do that `\sbox` can't?

Comment: @PeterGrill `\savebox` accepts optional arguments the same way as `\makebox` does (after the mandatory first argument to `\savebox`, of course). So you can do `\savebox{\foo}[2\width][l]{...}`, for instance.

Comment: @PeterGrill it has optional arguments (for length etc, or picture mode)