# Cache math content in savebox and account for math style

Tags: math-mode, boxes, scaling, scalerel

I am using [Create a \savebox in a Group and have it available outside of group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283373/create-a-savebox-in-a-group-and-have-it-available-outside-of-group) to cache some math content. However, I realized that there may be a case where the same math content needs to be cached for different math styles.

I attempted to make use of the `scalerel` package mentioned at [Proper-use-of-mathchoice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114594/4301) and include that in the style. But, I am not able to get the functionality of `\SavedStyle` to be applied to the math content.  The MWE below produces:

[image]

The desired output has a smaller `\sqrt` in the denominator:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CachedMathContent}{s O{} m}{%
    % #1 = not used here
    % #2 = String to use to store cached name. 
    %      Declared as optional (for compatibility with another related macro), but 
    %      in this example it is really mandatory. 
    % ---------
    % Code to check that #2 was provided has been omitted here.
    \ThisStyle{% scalerel pacakge
        \begingroup
        \edef\CachedMathBoxName{MathBox #2 \string\SavedStyle}%
        \ifcsdef{\CachedMathBoxName}{%
            %% Cached content already exists
        }{%
            %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283373/create-a-savebox-in-a-group-and-have-it-available-outside-of-group
            \global\expandafter\newsavebox\csname\CachedMathBoxName\endcsname%
            \global\expandafter\setbox\csname\CachedMathBoxName\endcsname%
                    \hbox{$\SavedStyle#3$}%
        }%
        \expandafter\usebox\csname\CachedMathBoxName\endcsname%
        \endgroup
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

Should be cramped: $\frac{1}{\CachedMathContent[sqrt phi]{\sqrt{\phi}}}$

\medskip
Should NOT be cramped: $\CachedMathContent[sqrt phi]{\sqrt{\phi}}$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: the whole point of boxes is that typesetting is frozen, if you need different settings why not just use a command (macro) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But I only occasionally use different styles. In most cases there will only be one style.  This was just to handle that case.  But, yes, I have been rethinking things -- original motivation for doing this was for efficiency in re-typesetting (and other related functions).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thought the `scalerel` package handled math styles and it does for most cases, but I can't make it work as in the MWE for some reason.

Comment: oh your example code is wrong! hang on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CachedMathContent}{s O{} m}{%
    % #1 = not used here
    % #2 = String to use to store cached name. 
    %      Declared as optional (for compatibility with another related macro), but 
    %      in this example it is really mandatory. 
    % ---------
    % Code to check that #2 was provided has been omitted here.
    \ThisStyle{% scalerel pacakge
        \begingroup
\edef\x{\SavedStyle}%
\typeout{\meaning\x}%
        \edef\CachedMathBoxName{MathBox #2 \expandafter\string\x}%
        \ifcsdef{\CachedMathBoxName}{%
            %% Cached content already exists
        }{%
            %% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283373/create-a-savebox-in-a-group-and-have-it-available-outside-of-group
\typeout{\meaning\CachedMathBoxName}%
            \global\expandafter\newsavebox\csname\CachedMathBoxName\endcsname%
            \global\expandafter\setbox\csname\CachedMathBoxName\endcsname%
                    \hbox{$\SavedStyle#3$}%
        }%
        \expandafter\usebox\csname\CachedMathBoxName\endcsname%
        \endgroup
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

Should be cramped: 
$\frac{1}{\CachedMathContent[sqrt phi]{\sqrt{\phi}}}$
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\phi}}$

\medskip
Should NOT be cramped:
$\CachedMathContent[sqrt phi]{\sqrt{\phi}}$ 
$\sqrt{\phi}$ 

\end{document}
```

The intention of the code was to save a box based on the supplied argument and the current style but

```
    \edef\CachedMathBoxName{MathBox #2 \string\SavedStyle}%
```

uses `#2` and the literal string `\SavedStyle` it does not use the definition of `\SavedStyle` (it would not need it to be defined at all).

You need to fully expand that macro to something like `\textstyle` and then apply `\string` to *that* hence the `\edef` and `\expandafter`.

Comment: I have left it here but the `\global` in `\global\expandafter\newsavebox` can not possibly do anything useful.  (it just makes the definition of  `\reserved@a` in `\@ifdefinable`  global)