# How to transfer math style in \hbox_set?

Tags: math-mode, boxes, expl3, scalerel

This question is kind of follow up question of the following

- [How to capture the current math style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78872/4918)
- [Is there a test for the different styles inside maths mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1223/4918)
- [Cache math content in savebox and account for math style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286632/4918)

There are some suggestions, but I wasn’t able to get the following MWE to work with the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` construct. I want to save some content math *or* text in an hbox while keeping the correct math style. At the moment everything is in double script style if it is put in my box.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse,scalerel,parskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

% - #1: Box-Register
% - #2: Content
\cs_new:Npn \tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox:nn #1#2 {
   \mode_if_math:TF {
      \ThisStyle {
      \hbox_gset:Nn #1 {
         \(
            \SavedStyle
            #2
         \)
      }
      }
   } {
      \hbox_gset:Nn #1 {
         #2
      }
   }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox:nn { Nn, NN }


\NewDocumentCommand { \boxtest } { m } {
   \tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
   \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
}

\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\boxtest{Box}

$a \boxtest{a}$

$a^2 a^{\boxtest{2}}$

$\frac{2}{3} \boxtest{\frac{2}{3}}$

\[\frac{2}{3} \boxtest{\frac{2}{3}}\]

\end{document}
```

As I need to use `mathspec` I’m bound to XeTeX and can't use LuaTeXs `\mathstyle` primitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put `\ThisStyle` as the first thing of `\boxtest`, while leaving `\SavedStyle` where it had been.

There is no need for the `\SavedStyle` and `\ThisStyle` to be part of the same macro, as long as `\SavedStyle` is effectively called within the argument to `\ThisStyle`.

It took me a bit to see what the actual problem was with Tobi's code.  To reiterate from my comment below,   the OP is generating the `\hbox` within the confines of the `\ThisStyle`, but is trying to employ it outside the argument of `\ThisStyle`. The macro `\ThisStyle` is a glorified version of `\mathchoice`, which will generate boxes in all mathstyles and choose which one to use at the last moment. By using the generated `\hbox` outside the `\ThisStyle` argument (i.e., `\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box`), the OP is using it outside the `\mathchoice` and thus just using the last of the 4 `\hbox`es generated, which will always be `\scriptscriptstyle`.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse,scalerel,parskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% - #1: Box-Register
% - #2: Content
\cs_new:Npn \tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox:nn #1#2 {
   \mode_if_math:TF {
%      \ThisStyle {
      \hbox_gset:Nn #1 {
         \(
            \SavedStyle
            #2
         \)
      }
%      }
   } {
      \hbox_gset:Nn #1 {
         #2
      }
   }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox:nn { Nn, NN }


\NewDocumentCommand { \boxtest } { m } {\ThisStyle{%
   \tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
   \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\boxtest{Box}

$a \boxtest{a}$

$a^2 a^{\boxtest{2}}$

$\frac{2}{3} \boxtest{\frac{2}{3}}$

\[\frac{2}{3} \boxtest{\frac{2}{3}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, although this works I don’t think this is a good solution as one always must remember to use `\tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox` inside a `\ThisStyle`. Do you know why it doesn’t work when `\ThisStyle` is part of the definition of the boxing macro?

Comment: @Tobi I do not understand LaTeX3 to know where the problem arises when all the calls are self contained in the `\tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox` macro.  I suppose you could put a LaTeX2e wrapper around the macro, i.e., define a macro which only invokes `\ThisStyle` and calls on `\tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox`...

Comment: @Tobi A little play testing reveals inside `\tobiw_set_text_or_math_hbox`, that the `scalerel` mode switch `\m@switch`, which carries the math style in the form of `D`, `T`, `S`, or `s`, is properly set just prior to the `\hbox_gset`, but becomes `s` inside of the `\hbox_gset`, thus putting everything into `\scriptscriptstyle`, regardless of value just prior to the `\hbox_gset`.  If I knew anything about LaTeX3, I might suspect a bug, for changing macro values, but as I said, I don't understand the LaTeX3 syntax at all.

Comment: Thanks for investigation further. This seems to be a strange behaviour. Maybe someone of the L3 team can tell us more … @Joseph Wright I’d be glad if you could take a look, please :-)

Comment: @Tobi I realize what the problem is. You are generating the `\hbox` within the confines of the `\ThisStyle`, but you are trying to employ it outside the argument of `\ThisStyle`.  The macro `\ThisStyle` is a glorified version of `\mathchoice`, which will generate boxes in *all* mathstyles and choose which one to use at the last moment.  By using it outside the `\ThisStyle` argument (`\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box`), you are using it outside the `\mathchoice` and thus just using the last of the 4 `\hbox`es generated, which will always be `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: Hi, the requirement of to remind using the box in `\ThisStyle` is a bit unhandy, thats why I decided to stick to LuaTeX (I wanted to use XeTeX because the font loading takes so much longer in Lua), which has a simple `\mathstyle` primitive I can use …

Answer (score 1):

Since the `\ThisStyle`-`\SavedStyle`-solution requires to much thinking on the authors/users side (i.e. *me*…), I decided to use LuaTeX, which has a simple primitive `\mathstyle` holding an integer for the current math style. Then it is quite easy to save the current math style:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt,parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

\cs_new_eq:NN \tobi_saved_math_style: \textstyle
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_save_math_style: {
   \int_case:nn { \mathstyle } {
      { \displaystyle } { \cs_set_eq:NN \tobi_saved_math_style: \displaystyle }
      { \textstyle } { \cs_set_eq:NN \tobi_saved_math_style: \textstyle }
      { \scriptstyle } { \cs_set_eq:NN \tobi_saved_math_style: \scriptstyle }
      { \scriptscriptstyle } { \cs_set_eq:NN \tobi_saved_math_style: \scriptscriptstyle }
   }
}


% - #1: Box register
% - #2: font switches (always outside math)
% - #3: box content
\cs_new:Npn \tobi_set_text_or_math_hbox:nnn #1#2#3 {
   \mode_if_math:TF {
      \tobi_save_math_style:
      \hbox_gset:Nn #1 {
         #2
         \(
            \m@th
            \tobi_saved_math_style:
            #3
         \)
      }
   } {
      \hbox_set:Nn #1 {
         #2 #3
      }
   }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobi_set_text_or_math_hbox:nnn { Nnn, NNN, NnN, NNn }


\tikzset {
   highlight~node/.style = {
      fill = yellow, inner~sep = \z@,
   },
}

% - #1: content (text or math)
\NewDocumentCommand{ \highlight }{ m }{
   \tobi_set_text_or_math_hbox:Nnn \l_tmpa_box { \bfseries \boldmath } { #1 }
   \begin{tikzpicture} [ baseline = (N.base) ]
      \node [ highlight~node ] (N) {
         \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\begin{document}

\highlight{High}light

$super^{\highlight{super}^{\highlight{script}}}$

$\highlight{\frac{text}{style}}$

\[\highlight{\frac{display}{style}}\]

\end{document}
```

See [Value of LuaTeX’s \mathstyle in \frac (de)nominator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371134/4918) for a follow-up question.

Comment: IMHO `\tobi_saved_math_style:` should be a variable – you're using it like one

Comment: @clemens: good point, so you would use `\l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl`?

Comment: probably yes, and then just set it `\tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \displaystyle }`

Comment: @clemens: Seems reasonable :-) thanks