# Savebox from within enumerate

Tags: macros

I'm completely puzzled by this: I'm trying to create a simple command that will modify a savebox from an enumerate, and I've worked it down to a minimal example of some weirdness:

```latex
...
% Create our command
\newcommand{\hello}{
\savebox{\tmp}{Works!}
}
% Setup the box
\newsavebox{\tmp}
\savebox{\tmp}{Doesn't work!}

\hello

\usebox{\tmp}
% Will put: Works!
```

If I run the command from inside an enumerate, it does not work:

```latex
% Create our command
\newcommand{\hello}{
\savebox{\tmp}{Works!}
}
% Setup the box
\newsavebox{\tmp}
\savebox{\tmp}{Doesn't work!}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Something \hello
\end{enumerate}

\usebox{\tmp}
% Will put: Doesn't work!
```

I have absolutely no clue why it does this. No warnings or errors are given, and it does this on both pdfLatex and XeLaTex (the only two I had available to test). Any clues would be much appreciated!

Comment: `enumerate` creates a local group that isolates the effect of `\hello` to within the `enumerate` group.  Therefore, duplicate?? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283373/create-a-savebox-in-a-group-and-have-it-available-outside-of-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that the `\savebox` is exercised in a group, and is scope limited to within the `enumerate`.

Stealing David's answer here, [Create a \savebox in a Group and have it available outside of group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283373/create-a-savebox-in-a-group-and-have-it-available-outside-of-group), and applying it to the OP's situation.  In essence, substitute the primitives for `\savebox` and make them `\global`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% Create our command
\newcommand{\hello}{
\global\expandafter\setbox\csname tmp\endcsname\hbox{Works!}
}
% Setup the box
\newsavebox{\tmp}
\savebox{\tmp}{Doesn't work!}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Something \hello
\usebox{\tmp} inside group

\end{enumerate}

\usebox{\tmp} outside group
% Will put: Doesn't work!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Technically, a given savebox should always be handled globally or locally.  Here is one way to do that, by introducing global macros

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\gnewsavebox[1]{\global\newsavebox#1}
\newcommand\gsavebox[2]{\global\setbox#1\hbox{#2}}
\begin{document}
% Create our command
\newcommand{\hello}{\gsavebox{\tmp}{Works!}
}
% Setup the box
\gnewsavebox{\tmp}
\gsavebox{\tmp}{Doesn't work!}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Something \hello
\usebox{\tmp} inside group

\end{enumerate}

\usebox{\tmp} outside group
% Will put: Doesn't work!
\end{document}
```